# Find distance between two lines (OpenCV)

Tags: opencv

I have the below image after some conversions.

How can I find a distance between these two lines?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this would be
 - Scan across a row until you find a pixel above a threshold.
 - Keep scanning until you find a pixel below the threshold.
 - Count the pixels until the next pixel above the threshold.
 - Take the average across a number of rows sampled from the image (or all rows)
 - You'll need to know the image resolution (e.g. dpos per inch) to convert the count to an actual distance

An efficient method to scan across rows can be found in [the OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#the-efficient-way)

A more complicated approach would use [Houghlines](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) to extract lines. It will give you two points on each line (hopefully you only have two). From that it is possible to work out a distance formula, assuming the lines are parallel.

Answer (score 0):

A skeleton code (not efficient, just readable so that you know how to do it) would be,

```
cv::Mat source = cv::imread("source.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
std::vector<int> output;
int threshold = 35, temp_var; // Change in accordance with data
int DPI = 30; // Digital Pixels per Inch

for (int i=0; i<source.cols; ++i)
{
    for (int j=0; j<source.rows; ++j)
    {
        if (source.at<unsigned char>(i,j) > threshold)
        {
            temp_var = j;
            for (; j<source.rows; ++j)
                if (source.at<unsigned char>(i,j) > threshold)
                    output.push_back( (j-temp_var)/DPI ); // Results are stored in Inch
        }
    }
}
```

Afterwards, you could take an average of all the elements in `output`, etc.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions:**

- You have only two continuous lines without any break in between.
- No other pixels (noise) apart from the lines

**My proposed solution: Almost same as given above**

- Mark leftmost line as line 1. Mark rightmost line as line 2.
- Scan the image (Mat in OpenCV) from the leftmost column and make a list of points matching the pixel value of line 1
- Scan the image (Mat in OpenCV) from the rightmost column and make a list of points matching the pixel value of line 2

Calculate the distance between points from that list using the code below.

```
public double euclideanDistance(Point a, Point b){
    double distance = 0.0;
    try{
        if(a != null && b != null){
            double xDiff = a.x - b.x;
            double yDiff = a.y - b.y;
            distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xDiff,2) + Math.pow(yDiff, 2));
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Something went wrong in euclideanDistance function in "+Utility.class+" "+e.getMessage());
    }
    return distance;
}
```